# Connection pooling handling in Cassandra?

Tags: java, cassandra, nosql, datastax

I am using Cassandra Database and Datastax driver for connection in my Java application. I used following code to make Pooling Option in Cassandra from my Java client.

```
 static Session connect() {
    String contactPoint = "localhost";
    String keySpace = "ks1";

    if(session == null) {
        PoolingOptions poolingOptions = new PoolingOptions().setConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.REMOTE, 4, 10);

        cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint(contactPoint).withPoolingOptions(poolingOptions)
                .withCompression(Compression.SNAPPY).build();
        cluster.init();
        for (Host host : cluster.getMetadata().getAllHosts()) {
            System.out.printf("Address: %s, Rack: %s, Datacenter: %s, Tokens: %s\n", host.getAddress(),
                    host.getDatacenter(), host.getRack(), host.getTokens());
        }
        session = cluster.connect(keySpace);
    }
    return session;
  }
```

Without Pooling options, if I make connection with Cassandra and read 100000 Records from Database, can consume it with in 2 Seconds.

If with the help of Pooling Options and sending request from 20 threads simultaneously, same amount of records take nearly 19 to 24 seconds to consume data on each thread.

Is it a correct approach to use the Connection Pool or is there any configuration needed on the Cassandra Server end ?

> Note: I am using Single Node Cassandra Cluster, Which is installed on
>   Windows 8 PC.